# Input a frequency distribution with unequal class widths and estimate the mean and median

Tags: frequency

The websites I have visited and the texts available to me determine the mean of an unequal frequency distribution using

mean = Sum(class marks x frequency) / Sum(frequency).

This is an example I extracted from the internet:

[image]

The author computed the mean wickets as 152.889, which I recoded in Mathematica as

```
midpts = {40, 80, 125, 200, 300, 400};
freq = {7, 5, 16, 12, 2, 3};   
mean = midpts . freq /Total[freq] // N
median = 100.5 + ((Total[freq]/2 - (7 + 5))/50) 16
```

Is it a correct solution? How about the unequal class widths?

Comment: Is there some reason why the actual number of wickets is not available?  Using the midpoint of the class can be a reasonable choice but that will just be an approximation (to an unknown degree) to the mean of the raw numbers.  For a median I think that maybe the best one could do is find the "median class" where at least 50% of the observations are less than or equal to that class and where at least 50% of the observations are greater than or equal to that class.  If there was some theoretical underlying distribution, then one could do much better.

Comment: Similar question posted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2094513).

Answer (score 2):

If it were up to me, I'd do something like this:

```
dist = MixtureDistribution[
   {7, 5, 16, 12, 2, 3},
   DiscreteUniformDistribution /@ {
     {21, 60}, {61, 100}, {101, 150}, 
     {151, 250}, {251, 350}, {351, 450}
   }
];
N @ Mean @ dist
```

> 153.389

This also generalizes easily for other statistics:

```
N @ StandardDeviation @ dist
```

> 94.3305

```
Quantile[dist, {0.1, 0.5, 0.9}]
```

> {46, 133, 275}

It might be possible to use `HistogramDistribution` to do this, but I can't think of a way right now.

## Edit and disclaimer

Anyone reading the comments on this answer will have noticed that the choice to use uniform distributions is only valid when you have absolutely no better way to assign probabilities within each class. In the case of cricket, it's quite likely that you can do better, since the very lowest and very highest values for "number of wickets" should be less likely than the ones in the middle (based on the general knowledge that the data should cluster roughly towards the middle). In general, I'd say that this is not a straightforward problem and for real applications you should probably ask someone with good knowledge of statistics how to deal with this exactly.

Comment: This neatly allows one to use most (if not all) of *Mathematica*'s statistical summary functions but with just the information given by the OP, how do you justify the assumption of a discrete uniform distribution for each class?

Comment: @JimB Well, wickets are discrete things, so obviously it should be a discrete distribution. Since we have no further information about the distribution within each class, the principle of indifference (i.e., maximum entropy) dictates that a uniform distribution is the appropriate choice. However, if you want to argue otherwise based on some prior information you have about cricket, be my guest. I guess you could also try to construct a max-ent distribution for the whole dataset instead of for each class, but that's more work than I'm willing to do here ;).

Comment: @JimB Actually, I'm pretty sure that maximizing the entropy of each bin also maximizes the entropy of the whole distribution unless you add extra constraints about the relationships between the bins. Some sort of smoothness constraint about how the counts from in one bin should transition to the next, for example.

Comment: Yes, the number of wickets consists of non-negative integers.  We agree on that. It is the assumption that the distribution is uniform on the integers in each class for which I ask how you justify that given the information given from the OP.  That assumption would seem very unlikely especially for the first and last class.  My point is that giving the OP a procedure that is loaded with unstated assumptions, is not necessarily a good thing even if it is what reasonable folks or most folks end up doing.  Maximizing entropy does not necessarily make things "correct".

Comment: @JimB Agreed, but I'd also argue that doing anything more refined than this is pretty far beyond the scope of this site and encroaches on CrossValidated territory. In fact, I'd argue that you'd be hard pressed to find two statisticians who agree on a better procedure for this problem. The max-ent approach is easy to grasp and the assumptions aren't that wild. It's limitations are also obvious enough. The method is perfectly justified as long as no additional assumptions can be formulated or additional prior information motivated. So if you want me to improve, what prior info am I overlooking?

Comment: @JimB In fact, I am very much inclined to argue here that in the absence of any other prior information (say we completely forget what cricket even is), the uniform distributions are the only correct choice here. Any other choice would be arbitrary in some way or another and is more likely to introduce extra bias rather than reduce it. The only reason anyone should be reaching for a more sophisticated model is the possession of extra prior information.

Comment: I think we're in complete agreement.  I only argue for being explicit with the assumptions.  And, for whatever it's worth, I think lots of statistical questions on this site really should be addressed at CrossValidated for "what to do" and then here for "implementation". (And on a different subject:  thanks for your efforts for using more Bayesian methods.)

Comment: Good idea. I added a "statistical disclaimer" to the answer ;).

Answer (score 0):

The example in question is of the form common in introductory college statistics. The raw data is assumed lost else there would be no ambiguity. The formula usually used to estimate the mean is :

mean = Sum(class marks x frequency) / Sum(frequency)

without regards to uniformity of the class widths, like this:

```
midpts = {40, 80, 125, 200, 300, 400};
freq = {7, 5, 16, 12, 2, 3};
Total[freq]/2 // N
mean = midpts . freq /Total[freq] // N

152.889
```

The website where I extracted the example gave the same answer. If we had use DiscreteUniformDistribution, the answer is almost similar.

If the class widths are the same, the estimated answers are consistent and the formula is applicable. No problem here.

I'm uncertain if the class widths are not uniform. Do we need to introduce any weighting to correct for the unequal distribution?

My approach is this:

(1) Divide the class widths into a uniform value of 1, then the solution would be

```
midpts = Range[21, 450];
freq = Join[Table[7, {40}], Table[5, {40}], Table[16, {50}], 
   Table[12, {100}], Table[2, {100}], Table[3, {100}]];   
mean = midpts . freq /Total[freq] // N

184.124
```

(2) Use a probability distribution via Piecewise definition:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{7, 21 <= x <= 60},
                {5, 61 <= x <= 100},
                {16, 101 <= x <= 150},
                {12, 151 <= x <= 250},
                {2, 251 <= x <= 350},               
                {3, 351 <= x <= 450}}, 0]
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[f[x], {x, 21, 450, 1}, Method -> "Normalize"];
Mean[dist] // N

184.124
```

I'm unsure if my approach is correct and is hoping someone would guide me to the correct solution or help to give me some references (website or text).

Thanks in anticipation.